# Tensorflow: When are variable assignments done in sess.run with a list?

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, variable-assignment, timing

I have thought that variable assignments are done after all operations in a list given to sess.run, but the following code returns different results at different execution. It seems randomly run operations in the list and assign the variable after the run of the operation in the list.

```
a = tf.Variable(0)
b = tf.Variable(1)
c = tf.Variable(1)
update_a = tf.assign(a, b + c)
update_b = tf.assign(b, c + a)
update_c = tf.assign(c, a + b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(initialize_all_variables)
  for i in range(5):
    a_, b_, c_ = sess.run([update_a, update_b, update_c])
```

I'd like to know the timing of variable assignments.
Which are correct: "update_x -> assign x -> ... -> udpate_z -> assign z" or "update_x -> udpate_y -> udpate_z -> assign a, b, c"? (where (x, y, z) is a permutation of (a, b, c))
In addition, if there is a way that realize the latter assignment (assignment are done after all operations in the list are done), please let me know how to realize it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The three operations `update_a`, `update_b`, and `update_c` have no interdependencies in the dataflow graph, so TensorFlow may choose to execute them in any order. (In the current implementation, it is possible that all three of them will be executed in parallel on different threads.) A second nit is that reads of variables are cached by default, so in your program the value assigned in `update_b` (i.e. `c + a`) may use the original or the updated value of `a`, depending on when the variable is first read.

If you want to ensure that the operations happen in a particular order, you can use [`with tf.control_dependencies([...]):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#control_dependencies) blocks to enforce that operations created within the block happen after operations named in the list.  You can use [`tf.Variable.read_value()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/variables#Variable.read_value) inside a `with tf.control_dependencies([...]):` block to make the point at which the variable is read explicit.

Therefore, to if you want to ensure that `update_a` happens before `update_b` and `update_b` happens before `update_c`, you could do:

```
update_a = tf.assign(a, b + c)

with tf.control_dependencies([update_a]):
  update_b = tf.assign(b, c + a.read_value())

with tf.control_dependencies([update_b]):
  update_c = tf.assign(c, a.read_value() + b.read_value())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mrry. I appreciated it and understood how to specify the ordering of operations in my code.

Then, I have one more question about your answer. If operations in a list have some interdependencies, are their values assigned after all operations are executed? And in that case, what is the ordering of the execution of operations by default (without using `tf.control_dependencies`).

Comment: What do you mean by "operations in a list"? In general, assign ops can run as soon as their new value is available. Variable-read ops can run as soon as the step begins.  However, without explicit control (or data) dependencies, an assignment to a variable can happen before or after the same variable is read, depending on how the ops are scheduled. The default ordering is undefined in this case.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous qustion. I mean an operation list like `[op1, op2, op3]`. I might have misunderstanding. The pseudo code: `v = tf.Variable(0), c = tf.constant(3), add = tf.add(v, c), update = tf.assign(v, add), mul = tf.mul(add, update), sess.run([mul, mul])` gives `[9, 9]` not `[9, 36]`. So I thought assignment is done after all operations in the list `[mul, mul]`, like mul -> mul -> assign, not mul -> assign -> mul -> assign.

Comment: @Sarah please check my answer!

Comment: Ah, I understand why that's confusing. When you call `sess.run([x, y, z])` once, TensorFlow executes each op that those tensors depend on one time only (unless there's a `tf.while_loop()` in your graph). If a tensor appears twice in the list (like `mul` in your example), TensorFlow will execute it once and return two copies of the result. To run the assignment more than once, you must either call `sess.run()` multiple times, or use `tf.while_loop()` to put a loop in your graph.

Comment: Thank you @kmario23 for explaining the detailed behavior of my code. In addition, thanks to @mrry's explanation, I finally understood `sess.run(list)` behavior. Thank you both!

Comment: you're welcome! 
@mrry Thanks for shedding more light on this!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this example of yours',

```
v = tf.Variable(0)
c = tf.constant(3)
add = tf.add(v, c)
update = tf.assign(v, add)
mul = tf.mul(add, update)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    res = sess.run([mul, mul])
    print(res)
```

***Output:  [9, 9]***

You get `[9, 9]` and this is in fact what we've asked it to do. Think of it like this:

During the run, once `mul` is taken from the list, it looks for the definition of this and finds `tf.mul(add, update)`. Now, it needs the value of `add` which leads to `tf.add(v, c)`. So, it plugs in the value of `v` and `c`, gets the value of `add` as 3.

Ok, now we need the value of `update` which is defined as `tf.assign(v, add)`. We have values of both `add` (which it computed just now as 3) & `v`. So, it updates the value of `v` to be 3 which is also the value for `update`.

Now, it has values for both `add` and `update` which are 3. Thus, the multiplication yields 9 in `mul`.

Based on the result that we get, I think, for the next item(operation) in the list, it just returns the just computed value of `mul`. I'm not sure whether it does the steps again or just returns the same (cached?) value it just computed for `mul` realizing that we've the result or these operations happen in parallel(for each element in the list). Maybe @mrry or @YaroslavBulatov can comment on this part please?

---

Quoting @mrry's comment:

> When you call `sess.run([x, y, z])` once, TensorFlow executes each op that those tensors depend on **one time only** (unless there's a `tf.while_loop()` in your graph). If a tensor appears twice in the list (like `mul` in your example), TensorFlow will execute it once and return *two copies* of the result. To run the assignment more than once, you must either call `sess.run()` multiple times, or use `tf.while_loop()` to put a loop in your graph.