# Tensorflow: assign multiple variable values in single run without recomputation of other expressions

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm new to Tensorflow, and I'm sorry, because this seems to be a very basic question, but unfortunately I can't find anything on Google, maybe I'm using wrong keywords.

I have some expressions derived from placeholders (as far as I understand the logic of tensorflow), and a few variables that need to be evaluated without recomputing "placeholdered" expressions. Below is my quite ugly code (which is supposed to be manually constructed 3-layer neural network) where evaluation happens in a loop.

The problem is that when I computed derived expressions (ys, deltas), I want to evaluate all the weights in a single run without incorrect recomputation of ys and deltas, which I think is supposed to happen at the moment. There are probably other errors in this code which prevent it from working correctly (however, 1-layer code written in this way works and gives its 92% of accuracy as expected), but it's difficult to figure it out until at least computation stages are not messed up.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)


#launch tensorflow session
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(
  intra_op_parallelism_threads=4)) 

def nonlin(x,deriv=False): # I want my custom activation function
    if(deriv==True):
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)*(1 - tf.nn.sigmoid(x))

    return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)



#placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

# Variables ----------------

#weights and biases
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10])) # 784x10 matrix (because we have 784 input features and 10 outputs)
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,10])) 
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,10])) 
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

# ---------------------

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


# derived expressions -------------------------
# Forward pass 

y1 = nonlin(tf.matmul(x,W1) + b1)
y2 = nonlin(tf.matmul(y1,W2) + b2)
y3 = nonlin(tf.matmul(y2,W3) + b3)


error3 = y_ - y3 # quadratic cost derivative



# Backward pass 
delta3 = tf.multiply(error3,nonlin(y3, deriv=True))  #assign delta

error2 = tf.matmul(delta3,W3, transpose_b=True)
delta2 = tf.multiply(error2,nonlin(y2, deriv=True))

error1 = tf.matmul(delta2,W2, transpose_b=True)
delta1 = tf.multiply(error1,nonlin(y1, deriv=True))


learning_rate = 0.1

# And my ugly update step which is not working:------------------------

w1_assign = tf.assign(W1, tf.add(W1, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(x,-1), tf.expand_dims(delta1,-1), transpose_b=True), 0)) ))
b1_assign = tf.assign(b1, tf.add(b1, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta1, 0)) ))

w2_assign = tf.assign(W2, tf.add(W2, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(y1,-1), tf.expand_dims(delta2,-1), transpose_b=True), 0)) ))
b2_assign = tf.assign(b2, tf.add(b2, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta2, 0)) ))

w3_assign = tf.assign(W3, tf.add(W3, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(y2,-1), tf.expand_dims(delta3,-1), transpose_b=True), 0)) ))
b3_assign = tf.assign(b3, tf.add(b3, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta3, 0)) ))

# accuracy evaluation ----------------------

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y3,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)) #a list of booleans.
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


# Main loop:----------------------

for epoch in range(1000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(1000)
  # apply across batch

  sess.run(w1_assign , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
  sess.run(b1_assign , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

  sess.run(w2_assign , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
  sess.run(b2_assign , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

  sess.run(w3_assign , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
  sess.run(b3_assign , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})


  # precision computation

  print(str(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})) + " / epoch: " + str(epoch))  # evaluate
```

---

UPDATE:

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309537/1692060), looks like if I provide arguments to sess.run in a list, I will have all the intermediate variables initialized only once, but the order is unknown. I tried my network then with the following modification which includes passing arguments in a list and additional variables to store new weights and make them not mess up with original ones (sorry for the extensive code, but I tried to make it immediately executable for you):

```
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)*(1 - tf.nn.sigmoid(x))

    return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)


#We start building the computation graph by creating nodes for the input images and target output classes.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])




#weights and biases
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([784,400])) # 784x10 matrix (because we have 784 input features and 10 outputs)
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([400]))

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([400,30])) # 784x10 matrix (because we have 784 input features and 10 outputs)
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30]))

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([30,10])) # 784x10 matrix (because we have 784 input features and 10 outputs)
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([10]))


# temporary containers to avoid messing up computations
W1tmp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,400])) # 784x10 matrix (because we have 784 input features and 10 outputs)
b1tmp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([400]))

W2tmp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([400,30])) # 400x30 matrix as second layer
b2tmp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))

W3tmp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30,10])) # 30x10 matrix (because we have 10 outputs)
b3tmp = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))




#Before Variables can be used within a session, they must be initialized using that session. 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


# multiplication across batch
# The tf.batch_matmul() op was removed in 3a88ec0. You can now use tf.matmul() to perform batch matrix multiplications (i.e. for tensors with rank > 2).

# Forward pass 

y1 = nonlin(tf.matmul(x,W1) + b1)
y2 = nonlin(tf.matmul(y1,W2) + b2)
y3 = nonlin(tf.matmul(y2,W3) + b3)


error3 = y_ - y3 # quadratic cost derivative



# Backward pass 
# error and y have same dimensions. It's only W that is unique
delta3 = tf.multiply(error3,nonlin(y3, deriv=True))  #assign delta



error2 = tf.matmul(delta3,W3, transpose_b=True)
delta2 = tf.multiply(error2,nonlin(y2, deriv=True))

error1 = tf.matmul(delta2,W2, transpose_b=True)
delta1 = tf.multiply(error1,nonlin(y1, deriv=True))



learning_rate = tf.constant(3.0)

# we first assign the deepest level to avoid extra evaluations

#with tf.control_dependencies([y1,y2,y3,delta1,delta2,delta3]): 
w1_assign = tf.assign(W1tmp, tf.add(W1, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(x,-1), tf.expand_dims(delta1,-1), transpose_b=True), 0)) ))
b1_assign = tf.assign(b1tmp, tf.add(b1, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta1, 0)) ))

w2_assign = tf.assign(W2tmp, tf.add(W2, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(y1,-1), tf.expand_dims(delta2,-1), transpose_b=True), 0)) ))
b2_assign = tf.assign(b2tmp, tf.add(b2, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta2, 0)) ))

w3_assign = tf.assign(W3tmp, tf.add(W3, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(y2,-1), tf.expand_dims(delta3,-1), transpose_b=True), 0)) ))
b3_assign = tf.assign(b3tmp, tf.add(b3, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta3, 0)) ))


w1_ok = tf.assign(W1,W1tmp)
w2_ok = tf.assign(W2,W2tmp)
w3_ok = tf.assign(W3,W3tmp)

b1_ok = tf.assign(b1,b1tmp)
b2_ok = tf.assign(b2,b2tmp)
b3_ok = tf.assign(b3,b3tmp)



#accuracy evaluation

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y3,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)) #a list of booleans.
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))



# we can use only single batch, just to check that everything works
#batch = mnist.train.next_batch(1000)

for epoch in range(10000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(1000)
  #train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})


  #When you call sess.run([x, y, z]) once, TensorFlow executes each op that those tensors depend on one time only (unless there's a tf.while_loop() in your graph). If a tensor appears twice in the list (like mul in your example), TensorFlow will execute it once and return two copies of the result. To run the assignment more than once, you must either call sess.run() multiple times, or use tf.while_loop() to put a loop in your graph.

  # write new variable values to containers
  sess.run([w1_assign,w2_assign,w3_assign,b1_assign,b2_assign,b3_assign] , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

  # write container contents into variables in a separate session
  sess.run([w1_ok,w2_ok,w3_ok,b1_ok,b2_ok,b3_ok])# , feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

  # precision computation

  print(str(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})) + " / epoch: " + str(epoch))  # evaluate
```

So the question is whether it is at least correct code for Tensorflow? I found network structure and learning rate which gives some results, but they still seem to be very poor (around 75%).

Comment: You don't need to calculate the backward pass.  use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Optimizers instead

Comment: @MZHm I know, but my future network will be fully custom, with a specific custom activation function.

Comment: @MZHm I have edited my question by adding new variant of my code based on the information I could find about evaluation order in Tensorflow.

Comment: what do you mean by `custom`? Could you implement the forward pass using functions from the Tensorflow Python API?

Comment: I want to implement another activation function, it is somewhat akin to RELU, but definitely is not present in standard libraries: [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02313.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02313.pdf) . As far as I understood, to work with custom activation function I need to implement it somewhere deep in the modules: [Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#adding-a-new-op).

Comment: @MZHm I tested both 1-layer MNIST network from Tensorflow tutorial and manual 1-layer network like the one above, and both worked and gave me 91-92% precision as expected. But I faced these troubles with implementation for 3 layers. Of course, my network structure may be very poor at the moment, but I just want to understand whether I use Tensorflow correctly for this particular problem (custom ANN using basic matrix algebra by hand).

Comment: @MZHm See also one more my comment above, I forgot to include you nickname there to notify.

Comment: If you can implement this activation function using existing tensorflow functions - you do not need to calculate the backwards pass yourself.

Comment: @MZHm Thanks very much for the suggestion, but that's a difficult question. so I need to think whether it is possible.

Comment: I strongly suggest doing that first.  If that doesn't work, please post what you did try (without the `tf.assign`), including the math formula, and I will try to help.