# Tensorflow: Interlieving two ragged tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to interleave two Ragged Tensors in Tensorflow? Example:
I have two RaggedTensors with the same "shape":

```
a = [[[10,10]],[[20,20],[21,21]]]
b = [[[30,30]],[[40,40],[41,41]]]
```

I would like to interleave them so the resulting tensor looks like this:

```
c = [[[10,10],[30,30]],[[20,20],[40,40],[21,21],[41,41]]]
```

Note that both tensors `a` and `b` always have the same "shape".

I have been trying to use the stack and the concat functions but both of them return non-desired shapes:

```
tf.stack([a,b],axis=-1)
c = [[[[10, 30], [10, 30]]], [[[20, 40], [20, 40]], [[21, 41], [21, 41]]]]

tf.concat([a,b],axis=-1)
c = [[[10, 10, 30, 30]], [[20, 20, 40, 40], [21, 21, 41, 41]]]
```

I have seen some other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952886/tensorflow-merge-two-2-d-tensors-according-to-even-and-odd-indices) for regular tensors that reshape the resulting tensor c after applying the stack/concat functions. E.g.,:

```
a = [[[10, 10]], [[20, 20]]]

b = [[[30, 30]], [[40, 40]]]

tf.reshape(
    tf.concat([a[..., tf.newaxis], b[..., tf.newaxis]], axis=1),
    [a.shape[0], -1, a.shape[-1]])

c = [[[10, 10],[30, 30]],[[20, 20],[40, 40]]]
```

However, as far as I know, since I am using Ragged Tensors the shape in some dimensions is None (I am using TF2.6).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a part of a preprocessing step, the `tf.data.Dataset` API is one route.  This has the benefit in using the "interleave" function of mixing up the interleaving pattern with different `block_length` settings and can interleave an arbitrary number of lists.

```py
# I made a little longer to emphasize raggedness
a = tf.ragged.constant([[[10,10]],[[20,20],[21,21],[23,23]]])
b = tf.ragged.constant([[[30,30]],[[40,40],[41,41]]])
c = tf.concat([a,b],axis=1)

NUM_ELEMENTS=7

# Option 1) more flexible
def ragged_to_ds(x):
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)

tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(c).interleave(ragged_to_ds, block_length=1).batch(NUM_ELEMENTS).get_single_element()

# Option 2) less mess but unbatch makes copies of the data
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(c).unbatch().batch(NUM_ELEMENTS).get_single_element()
```

The `tf.data.Dataset` API can be powerful and expressive and can help with a large number of data processing and rearranging tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, both, a and b, are tensors that are generated using the output of a Layer inside a call() function of a bigger model.